# Identifying a short story about advertising

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story at least twenty years ago about a man who spends a lot of money to rent a hovel because there is no advertising in it.  During any normal day everything advertises to him, but in this room he can find some peace.  I think he risks a death sentence, though...

Comment: This is vaguely familiar.

Comment: I don't know about twenty years ago, but twenty years from *now*, that's probably going to be **non-fiction**...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I t was "The Room"  I could vaguely remember the story up to where he rented the room, but then I couldn't remember the rest.  Now I know that's because there was no rest.

Some time ago my wife complained about advertising and I told her we still had it pretty good, and mentioned the story I had once read.  I said I'd try to find it.

Thanks Gabe Willard, and all the others who posted.

Answer (score 23):

It's Ray Russell. Published in Playboy (next to an ad, I imagine) in 1961 under the title "The Room". Just read it today. Short, sweet and freaky - subliminal sleep advertising, auto-on television, in-mirror ads, ads on towels and sheets, even money...
Don't wanna spoil it for you - so SPOILER!

> He doesn't risk a death sentence... BUT, he gets 1984ed, because the room without ads is just a front for "rehabilitation".

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four)?  The main characters rent a flat without a screen (and hence no **Big Brother** watching).  Not advertising, but they do get up to stuff 'deserving' of the death sentence.

Comment: This is exactly what came into my mind.  Not quite a short story, but it definitely fits.

Comment: Nah - the advertising is key in this short story, not the surveillance.

Answer (score 3):

The theme of ubiquitous advertising was used by Ann Warren Griffith in [“Captive Audience”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56704), in which a character goes to prison to escape the advertising after earplugs are declared illegal. That story was collected in [*Tomorrow, Inc.*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?278519) I checked, but none of the stories in that book match your description.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be JG Ballard's *The Subliminal Man*? The only detail that matches is that there's constant advertising, though.