# Very short short-story of a near-future with advertisments on everything, even toilet paper

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Very short short-story of a near future with advertisments everywhere, even on toilet paper. Maybe by Philip K Dick?

Can't think of anything else to add... googling turned up too many other things. Thanks!

Comment: Huh! This rings a bell, but it sounds like Frederik Pohl's "The Space Merchants", which is... not a short story. I read something like this in asimov's recently, but it's not quite the right thing.

Comment: Thanks! It's a long time ago, so maybe "The Space Merchants" was it. Being shanghaied in the plot rings a bell, but I may be confusing stories. OTOH if it has toilet paper advertising in it, any other story would have copied from it, it being from 1953 and seeming very original https://wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Merchants

Comment: The main reason I suggest it is that it's the absolute progenitor of the "mass advertisement dystopia" genre. The quote always stuck with me: "Think about smoking, think about Starrs, light a Starr. Light a Starr, think about Popsie, get a squirt. Get a squirt, think about Crunchies, buy a box. Buy a box, think about smoking, light a Starr."

Comment: [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8178/4495) also has interesting answers; _[The Room](https://jennre.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/the-room-ray-russell-1961/)_ sounds like it could fit the bill.

Comment: @MrLister Yes! Must be "The Room", I don't remember further details, but I did read "100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories" (in your second link). Thank you.

Comment: @hyperpallium Yep. A line from the story: "A few moments later, he was reading the ads for Now, the gentle instant laxative, and Stop, the bourbon-flavored paregoric, which were printed on alternating sheets of the bathroom tissue."

Comment: I know that *Spaceballs* has merchandising everywhere (even on toilet paper) but it is not a short...

Comment: If it is the room and you confirm it as such we can close it as a dupe, otherwise @MrLister could wire up an answer and you accept it. The dupe should probably lead from there to here if a good answer is written here.

Comment: @Edlothiad Hm? I thought OP's last comment was a confirmation. Did I jump the gun?

Comment: @user14111 possibly, I read that as "sounds familiar, may have been it as I did read that anthology", not "I've looked at the details and that is definitely the story I read". Either way, the answer on the other question is poor so I still suggest MrLister write up an answer with their research and we set this question as the dupe target. (Or be a hero and improve the answer there, without claiming the rep here.)

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm not sure which way the dupe arrow should go. The *question* here is really minimal. There isn't that much more in the old question, but how much can you say about a 2-page story?

Comment: I'd say it go from here to the older one for now, and if someone edits the old one to add in some details, *\*slow clap** otherwise someone could just hop on the rep train and provide and answer here.

Comment: I'm sure it's the story, because it's "short short", but can't check the details: don't have access to my copy, and nothing online except google books confirms it's in there, on p.178 https://books.google.com.au/books?id=mpUOAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22The+Room%22 The key was the anthology, in @MrLister's link - which wasn't in the other question's answers. If made into an answer, of course I'd select it.

Comment: If we're sure that this was it, do we really need to type up an answer? Can't we just go ahead and close it? I mean, [What's the short story where the man is sick and tired of advertising?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93725/4495) also was closed as a duplicate without answers...

Comment: It would be nice to have your link and anthology in an answer, so it's visible to future visitors. Also, something went wrong in that other question: instead of accepting the given answer, the asker self-answered, accepted their own answer, but included less information than the one given to them (and thanked the wrong person). Unsurprisingly, that accepted answer doesn't have the most votes. Improving that accepted answer would also work. It would be nice to consolidate all the question material too (last comment on the 2nd question you linked), so it's easier for google to hit.